# Why isn't it working when I try to use virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I want to use Django, but to do that, I have to get virtualenv first. I follow all the steps, but get stuck at the part `virtualenv [example]`. Every time I put that, it says `'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Please provide your code as well as details about how you've set up your virtual environment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command%2C+operable+program+or+batch+file

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in the django folder:

```
python -m virtualenv
```

After that, run

> .\scripts\activate